# evaluating a limit of a function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

> Let $a, b, c> 0$ and consider the differential equation $af''+bf'+cf = 0$ which satisfyies $f(0) = k$ and $f'(0) = 0.$ Let $t = \dfrac{b}{2\sqrt{ac}}.$ Define $f_t(x)$  to be the solution to the differential equation when $t > 1$ and $f_1(x)$ to be the solution when $t = 1.$ Determine the range of values of $b$ for which the following limit is defined $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{f_1(x)}{f_t(x)}.$
>
> Clarification: The values of $t$ are different in the numerator and denominator. Any one of $a, b, c$ can vary. So it's better to think of the numerator as being in terms of $b_1 = 2\sqrt{a_1c_1}$ and $a_1$ and of the denominator as being in terms of $b_2, a_2, $ and $c_2,$ where the pairs $(a_1, a_2), (b_1, b_2), (c_1, c_2)$ may be pairs of distinct numbers. I want to find the range of values of $b_2$ for which the above limit exists. WLOG, we can assume $a_1 = a_2$ and $c_1 = c_2.$

When $t>1,$ the solution is of the form $c_1e^{-(\beta -\gamma)x} + c_2e^{-(\beta+\gamma)x},$ where $\beta = \dfrac{b}{2a}$ and $\gamma = \dfrac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ and when $t = 1,$ it is of the form $c_1e^{-\beta t}+c_2te^{-\beta t},$ where $\beta = \dfrac{\sqrt{4ac}}{2a}=\sqrt{\dfrac{c}a}.$

After plugging in the initial values, I obtained $$f_t(x) = \dfrac{k(b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac})}{2\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}e^{-\frac{b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}x}-\dfrac{k(b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac})}{2\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}e^{-\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}x},$$ where $t>1,$ and $f_1(x) = ke^{-\frac{b}{2a}x}+\frac{b}{2a}kxe^{-\frac{b}{2a}x}.$ I checked, and these values satisfy the initial conditions. However, when I evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{f_1(x)}{f_t(x)}$ with $a$ and $c$ fixed, I get that it exists as long as $b > \sqrt{4ac},$ but this is nonsensical because that is the requirement when $t > 1.$ When $b \to \sqrt{4ac}^+,$ the limit only doesn't exist when $x \to -\infty$ and when $b \to \infty,$ the limit only doesn't exist when $x = 0,$ neither of which approaches infinity. I'm pretty sure I did my limit calculations correctly, so there may be something else wrong here.

Comment: Try dividing into cases depending on whether the discriminant b^2-4ac is positive, negative or 0.

Comment: @P.Lawrence I already did that and got the answers for $y_1(x)$ and $y_t(x)$. Just to clarify, I only care about the cases where $b^2-4ac > 0$ and when $b^2 - 4ac = 0.$ I know how to deal with the case when $b^2 -4ac < 0,$ but that's irrelevant for this problem.

Comment: Review your equations you have miscalculated $f_t(x)$

Comment: The function $f_t(x)$  should have an $x$ in it. your expression is basically $f_t(t)$

Comment: I can't see how it makes any sense to ask for the *range* of $\ b\ $ for which the limit $\ \lim_\limits{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f_1(x)}{f_t(x)}\ $ exists. Evaluation of the numerator *requires* that $\ b=2\sqrt{ac}\ $, in which case $\ t=1\ $, and the denominator must also be $\ f_1(x)\ $ if it's calculated with the same values of $\ a, b\ $ and $\ c\ $.

Comment: You cannot simultaneously compute $f_t(x)$ at $t=b/2\sqrt{ac}>1$ and at $t=1$ with $t$ defined as a function of $(a,b,c)$.

Comment: @NapD.Lover you are misunderstanding. The values of $t$ are different in the numerator and denominator. Any one of $a, b, c$ can vary. So it's better to think of the numerator as being in terms of $b_1 = 2\sqrt{a_1c_1}$ and $a_1$ and of the denominator as being in terms of $b_2, a_2, $ and $c_2,$ where the pairs $(a_1, a_2), (b_1, b_2), (c_1, c_2)$ may be pairs of distinct numbers. I want to find the range of values of $b_2$ for which the limit exists.

Comment: @Fred Jefferson But in the penultimate sentence of your question, there's no mention of any $\ a_1$, $\ b_1$, $\ c_1$, $\ a_2$, $\ b_2$, or  $\ c_2\ $, only of $\ a, b$, and $\ c\ $.  The condition $\ b>\sqrt{4ac}\ $ isn't nonsensical *unless* you try to use those *same* values of $\ a$, $\ b$ and $\ c$ to evaluate $\ f_1(x)\  $.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera but I was thinking of fixing $b > 2\sqrt{ac}$ and using $a, b^*, c$ to evaluate $f_1(x),$ where $b^* = 2\sqrt{ac}$.

Comment: @Fred Jefferson But in that case $\ b>\sqrt{4ac}\ $ still isn't "nonsensical".  However, if you fix $\ a\ $ and $\ c\ $, then since $\ b=2t\sqrt{ac}\ $, it doesn't make sense to talk about a "range of $\ b\ $", *unless* you're allowing $\ t\ $ to vary as well.  And unless there's a mistake in the calculations in my answer below (always a possibility), then $\ \lim_\limits{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{f_1(x)}{f_t(x)}=0\ $ for *any* $\ t>1\ $ (i.e. for any $\ b> 2\sqrt{ac}\ $ in this case.

Comment: Unless there's a mistake in the  calculations in my answer below, the statement that $\ a_1=a_2\ $ and $\ c_1=c_2\ $ can be assumed "without loss of generality" is incorrect.  According to my calculations, $\ \lim_\limits{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f_1(x)}{f_t(x)}=0\ $ for *any* $\ b_2>2\sqrt{a_2b_2}\ $ in that case. But if $\ a_2=3\ $, $\ a_1=5\ $, $\ c_1=c_2=1\ $, and $\ b_2=3.5\ $ (so $\ t=\frac{3.5}{2\sqrt{3}}\approx1.01 \ $) then $\ \frac{f_1(x)}{f_t(x)}\ $ does not converge as $\ x\rightarrow\infty\ $.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, I gather that if $\ f_t\ $ is a solution to the initial value problem
$$
a_tf''(x) + b_tf'(x) + c_tf(x)=0\ ,\\
f(0)=k, f'(0)=0
$$
where $\ a_t, b_t, c_t>0\ $ and $\ \frac{b_t}{2\sqrt{a_tc_t}}=t\ $, then the problem is to find the range of values of $\ b_t\ $ for any $\ t>1\ $ such that the ratio
$$
\frac{f_1(x)}{f_t(x)}
$$
converges as $\ x\rightarrow\infty\ $.  It is not clear to me from the statement of the question, or the OP's comments, exactly which of the quantities $\ t\ $, $\ a_t\ $, $\ b_t\ $, $\ c_t\ $ are to be considered fixed and which variable, or precisely what relations are assumed to hold between them, apart from the the fact that they're all positive, $\ t\ge1\ $, and $\ b_t=2t\sqrt{a_tc_t}\ $. Here, I shall assume that $\ a_1$, $\ c_1\ $  and $\ a_t$, $\ b_t$, and $\ c_t$ for $\ t>1\ $ can all vary independently of each other, subject only to the inequality $\ b_t>2\sqrt{a_tc_t}\ $ for $\ t>1\ $ and the positivity restrictions. Once these values have been given, the values of $\ b_1= 2\sqrt{a_1c_1}\ $ and $\ t= \frac{b_t}{2\sqrt{a_tc_t}}\ $ are determined.

For $\ t>1\ $,
$$
f_t(x)=\frac{k\left(b_t+r_t\right)e^{-\frac{\left(b_t-r_t\right)x}{2a_t}}}{2r_t}-\frac{k\left(b_t-r_t\right)e^{-\frac{\left(b_t+r_t\right)x}{2a_t}}}{2r_t}
$$
where $\ r_t=\sqrt{ b_t^2-4a_tc_t}\ $, and for $\ t=1\ $,
$$
f_1(x)=ke^{-x\sqrt{\frac{c_1}{a_1}}}\left(1+ x\sqrt{\frac{c_1}{a_1}}\right)\ .
$$
Therefore,
\begin{align}
\frac{f_1(x)}{f_t(x)}&=\frac{e^{\left(\frac{\left(b_t-r_t\right)}{2a_t}-\sqrt{\frac{c_1}{a_1}}\right)x}\left(1+ x\sqrt{\frac{c_1}{a_1}}\right)}{\left(\frac{k\left(b_t+r_t\right)}{2r_t}-\frac{k\left(b_t-r_t\right) e^{-\frac{r_tx}{a_t}}}{2r_t}\right)}\ .
\end{align}
Since $\ a_t, r_t > 0\ $, this ratio converges as $\ x\rightarrow\infty\ $ if and only if
$$
\frac{\left(b_t-r_t\right)}{2a_t}-\sqrt{\frac{c_1}{a_1}}<0\ ,
$$
or
$$
b_t-2a_t \sqrt{\frac{c_1}{a_1}}< \sqrt{ b_t^2-4a_tc_t}
$$
when it converges to $0$.  This inequality is automatically satisfied if $\ b_t\le 2a_t \sqrt{\frac{c_1}{a_1}}\ $.  On the other hand, if $\ b_t> 2a_t \sqrt{\frac{c_1}{a_1}}\ $, both sides of the inequality are positive, and it is therefore equivalent to the one obtained by squaring both sides:
$$
b_t^2-4a_tb_t \sqrt{\frac{c_1}{a_1}}+4a_t^2\left(\frac{c_1}{a_1}\right)<b_t^2-4a_tc_t\ ,
$$
which reduces to
$$
b_t>c_t \sqrt{\frac{a_1}{c_1}}+a_t \sqrt{\frac{c_1}{a_1}}\ .
$$
If $\ a_t \sqrt{\frac{c_1}{a_1}}\ge c_t \sqrt{\frac{a_1}{c_1}}\ $(i.e. if $\ \frac{a_t}{c_t}\ge \frac{a_1}{c_1}\ $, and, in particular, if $\ \frac{a_t}{c_t}= \frac{a_1}{c_1}\ $), then $\ b_t> 2a_t \sqrt{\frac{c_1}{a_1}}\ $ implies that $ b_t>$$c_t \sqrt{\frac{a_1}{c_1}}+$$a_t \sqrt{\frac{c_1}{a_1}}\ $, and so $\ \lim_\limits{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f_1(x)}{f_t(x)}=0\ $ for all $\ b_t>2\sqrt{a_tc_t}\ $ in this case.

On the other hand, if $\ \frac{a_t}{c_t}<\frac{a_1}{c_1}\ $, then $\ \frac{f_1(x)}{f_t(x)}=0\ $ does not converge to a finite limit whenever $\ 2a_t \sqrt{\frac{c_1}{a_1}}<$$b_t\le$$ c_t \sqrt{\frac{a_1}{c_1}}+$$a_t \sqrt{\frac{c_1}{a_1}}\ $.

Answer (score 0):

Considering

$$
f''+\alpha f'+\beta f = 0
$$

with $\alpha = \frac ba, \beta = \frac ca$ after solving the ODE with the established initial conditions we get

$$
\frac{f_1}{f_t} = \frac{\left(\alpha  \left(e^{\sqrt{\alpha ^2-4 \beta }}-1\right)+\sqrt{\alpha ^2-4 \beta }
   \left(e^{\sqrt{\alpha ^2-4 \beta }}+1\right)\right) e^{\frac{1}{2} (t-1) \left(\sqrt{\alpha ^2-4 \beta
   }+\alpha \right)}}{\alpha  \left(e^{t \sqrt{\alpha ^2-4 \beta }}-1\right)+\sqrt{\alpha ^2-4 \beta }
   \left(e^{t \sqrt{\alpha ^2-4 \beta }}+1\right)}
$$

now making $\beta=0$ we have

$$
\frac{f_1}{f_t}{\Big |}_{\beta=0}=\frac{\left(\alpha  \left(e^{\alpha }-1\right)+\alpha  \left(e^{\alpha }+1\right)\right) e^{\alpha 
   (t-1)}}{\alpha  \left(e^{\alpha  t}-1\right)+\alpha  \left(e^{\alpha  t}+1\right)}=1
$$

Follows a plot showing in light blue in the plane $\alpha\times\beta$, the stable region such that $\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{f_1}{f_t}=0$. In red is the stable region associated to $\alpha > 0, \beta = 0$

[image]

Note the parabolic shape associated to $\alpha^2-4\beta =0$